# C# Function as parameter

Tags: c#, function, delegates, arguments

I need help. I'm making a programm and i have a problem.

I have a constructor with delegate already:

```
public delegate bool delIsDone(int curState, int needState);
public Progress(delIsDone doneFunction) { ... }
```

I need to pass it without creating it outside of creation:

```
public bool check() { return true }
Progress p = new Progress(check);
```

I need to do something like this:

```
  Progress p = new ProgressChecker(bool check(int currentProgress, int needProgress) {
    return currentProgress < needProgress;
  });
```

Where ProgressChecker is a class that have method that check progress.

In loop i execute this function to get result. If function return "true" it's mean that "Achievement geted" and i need to hold it.

Thx for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the constructor you can pass in a function like so:

`ProgressChecker(Func<int,int,bool> checker)`

That means you can pass a function into the constructor for `ProgressChecker`

```
public bool checker (int a, int b)
{
    return a < b;
}

var t = new ProgressChecker(checker);
```

EDIT:

If you want to use the delegate, then in the `ProgressChecker` class, the constructor must take in that delegate type:

```
private delIsDone delIsDone;

public ProgressChecker(delIsDone delIsDone)
{
    this.delIsDone = delIsDone;
}
```

You can the pass a delegate instance like so:

```
public class Program
{
    public delegate bool delIsDone(int curState, int needState);

    public static bool checkNumbers(int a, int b)
    {
        return a < b;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = new ProgressChecker(new delIsDone(checkNumbers)); 
    // OR var t = new ProgressChecker(new delIsDone((a, b) => { return a < b; }));           
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a delegate already. And i used it in constructor. But how to pass function without creating it? P.S like: public void p()... New ProgressChecker(p)

Comment: At this time i'm creating function and then i'm passing it to constructor. But can i pass it like new P(MyFunction() { return 1; }) ?

Comment: Thank you for this: new delIsDone((a, b) => { return a < b; }

Comment: @HenkHolterman i need it. Because i have near 30 achievements. Each need it's own check =). New delIsDone(...) => ... looks much better and easier to add

Answer (score 0):

You can also create Expression Trees, it is my snippet for it (it can be easly converted to your example)

```
        //easy way
        Expression<Action<int>> printExpr = (arg) => Console.WriteLine(arg);
        printExpr.Compile()(10);

        //hard way
        ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "arg");
        MethodCallExpression methodCall = Expression.Call
            (
                  typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new[]
                  {
                      typeof(int)
                  }
             ),
             param
          );

        Expression.Lambda<Action<int>>(methodCall, param).Compile()(10); //execution
```

More information ca be gathered at [Generating Dynamic Methods with Expression Trees](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/09/14/generating-dynamic-methods-with-expression-trees-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx)